# Android load contacts code optimization

Tags: android, background-process

I've written an activity which loads all contacts of the phone and displays it at once in a `ListView`. The thing is, it takes time to load 400+ contacts and this is not very user friendly. Can anyone point me how can i make this activity run in the background\run faster, I've tried to use `AsyncTask` but apparently it uses a class rather and not an activity. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Im adding the code so it will be easier to understand how things work for now:

This is the Contacts class:

```
public class CustomContact 
{
    private String contactName;
    private String contactPhoneNumber;
    private boolean selected = false;

    public CustomContact() 
    {

    }

    public CustomContact(String contactName, String contactPhoneNumber, boolean selected) 
    {
        super();
        this.contactName = contactName;
        this.contactPhoneNumber = contactPhoneNumber;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getContactName()
    {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setContactName(String contactName) 
    {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getContactPhoneNumber() 
    {
        return contactPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setContactPhoneNumber(String contactPhoneNumber) 
    {
        this.contactPhoneNumber = contactPhoneNumber;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() 
    {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) 
    {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return contactPhoneNumber + " " + "\u200e" + contactName;
    } 
}
```

Now the code of the activity which uses the `CustomContacts` class:

```
public class ContactSelectActivity extends Activity 
{
          MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_select);
               //Generate list View from ArrayList
               displayListView();

               checkButtonClick();

            }

            private void displayListView()
            {

                    //Array list of countries
                    ArrayList<CustomContact> contactsList = new ArrayList<CustomContact>();


                    String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                                        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                                                        ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
                                                        };  
                    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME ;
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                                                          ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"+ ("1") + "'", 
                                                          null, sortOrder
                                                         );
                    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) 
                    {
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
                        {
                            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
                            {
                        // Query phone here. Covered next
                                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null); 
                                while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                                { 

                                    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                    CustomContact customContact = new CustomContact(name, phoneNumber, false);
                                    contactsList.add(customContact);
                                }

                                phones.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
                    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_contact_info, contactsList);
                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    // Assign adapter to ListView
                    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                    {

                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                            {
                                    CustomContact contact = (CustomContact) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                            }
                    });
            }

            private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomContact>
            {

                private ArrayList<CustomContact> contactList;

                public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 

                ArrayList<CustomContact> stateList) 
                {
                    super(context, textViewResourceId, stateList);
                    this.contactList = new ArrayList<CustomContact>();
                    this.contactList.addAll(stateList);
                }

            private class ViewHolder
            {
              TextView code;
              CheckBox name;
            }

        @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_contact_info, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
                holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)  
                    {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        CustomContact _contact = (CustomContact) cb.getTag();
                        _contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    }
                });

            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            CustomContact contact = contactList.get(position);
            holder.code.setText(" (" + contact.getContactName() + ")");
            holder.name.setText(contact.getContactPhoneNumber());
            holder.name.setChecked(contact.isSelected());
            holder.name.setTag(contact);

            return convertView;
        }
            }

        private void checkButtonClick() 
        {
            Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);

            myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                    responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");
                    ArrayList<CustomContact> contactList = dataAdapter.contactList;

                                            for(int i=0;i<contactList.size();i++)
                                            {
                                                 CustomContact contact = contactList.get(i);

                                                if(contact.isSelected())
                                                {
                                                    responseText.append("\n" + contact.getContactPhoneNumber());
                                                }
                                            }
                            }
                });
        }
}
```

Comment: What does your current implementation look like? Why are you loading 400+ contacts all at once? Are you using some variant of a `CursorAdapter`? (I'm guessing no, but you probably should be).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, please review the changes ive made in the post, now it contains the whole code. Im loadin 400+ contacts in my case, but i guess the average user has aprox 200 contacts but it still takes time to load. He needs to be able to select via checkbox the contacts he wants to interact with.